# Why can't inherited objects override prototype functions in the inheritance call?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

When you "inherit" in javascript, you can both inherit the prototype functions of the parent and within the same `Object.create()`, define new prototype methods. Why can you not override in this step, too?

Example: Fuz.baz() is not defined

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function () {
        this.baz();
    },
    baz: function () {
        console.log("original")
    }
}

function Fuz() {
    Foo.call(this);
}

Fuz.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype, {
    baz: function () {
        console.log("override");
    }
});

var c = new Foo();
c.baz();

var a = new Fuz();
a.baz();
```

Comment: that 2nd arg is not a propertyDescriptor... readup on createObject.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? *Foo*, called as a function, does nothing and returns *undefined*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you have to call `Object.create()` properly:

```
Fuz.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype, {
    baz: {
      value: function () {
        console.log("override");
      }
    }
});
```

The second argument to `Object.create()` should be a property descriptor object. Each entry defines a single property, and the values of those entries should be objects that provide the property value and other things like getters, setters, and access flags.